# Unable to install Pygame using pip

Tags: python, pygame, installation, pip

I'm trying to install Pygame. I am running Windows 7 with Enthought Python Distribution. I successfully installed `pip`, but when I try to install Pygame using `pip`, I get the following error:

> "Could not install requirement Pygame because of HTTP error HTTP error
>   400: Bad request for URL ..."

I can't find anything about this issue with a Google search, but I did find another Stack Overflow question that prompted the asker to use the following command:

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Cannot find command hg
```

I'm not sure what else to do, as everything I find with a Google search is for Mac, so I don't know how well I can follow those instructions on Windows.

Comment: If I remove the "hg" portion of the install command, I get the following error:

"Cannot determine archive format of c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-tnjf7m-build"

Comment: why dont you just download it from the pygame site

Comment: How do I install it once I download it?

Comment: its a .msi so i belive it auto installs http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: There is `mercurial` for Windows, it seems - have you tried it? http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WindowsInstall `hg` is the main mercurial command.

Comment: Given that mercurial is a python application, you can also install it with `pip install mercurial`.  This is handy if you want to put all of your build dependencies into one `requirements.txt` file to be installed with pip.

Answer (score 102):

**Steps to install PyGame using pip**

1. Install build dependencies (on linux):

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
   ```
2. Install mercurial to use `hg` (on linux):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mercurial
   ```

   On Windows you can use the installer: [Download](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download)
3. Use pip to install PyGame:

   ```
   pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
   ```

   If the above gives `freetype-config: not found` error (on Linux), then try `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` and then repeat 3.

**Alternative way:**

```
# Grab source
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

# Finally build and install
cd pygame
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 14.04. Building/installing it like this could be an accepted answer for pygame project.

Comment: Worked for me. It's still a little silly that Pygame doesn't have a proper release on PyPI...

Comment: `pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame` works well with Python 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.10 once you have all the dependencies installed. Since `ffmpeg` is currently not available as a package, I had to build it from source first (more dependencies needed...), but once that was done the pygame installation worked like a charm. Interestingly, cloning the repo and running `python3 setup.py build` did **not** work, for some reason, but pip did. Go figure...

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 15.10 running in VirtualBox), command #3  silently waited me to press Enter after cloning the package. After I pressed it, the installation process promptly began.

Comment: I'm confused. Why so many upvotes, when this is for the wrong OS? OP is using windows, so sudo won't work.

Comment: @Oddthinking First two steps are only for Linux. Window's executable installer is provided just above step 3.

Comment: brew install homebrew/python/pygame

Comment: This comment is incorrect in using bitbucket, as pygame moved to github a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 22):

Try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Answer (score 18):

An update to this may be required, as it stands in version 1.9.1 it should simply install using:

`pip install pygame`

However, it look like there is a bug with their pypi repository, see:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/59/pygame-has-no-pypi-page-and-cant-be

So, if you want the most recent release, you have to point directly at the ftp file ala:

`pip install http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz`

I suppose this will be fixed in the 1.9.2 release but for now this works.

I would note that the answer supplied by Pratyush works as well, but requires the user to install mercurial if they don't have it and downloads the trunk version, so really, not ideal unless you absolutely need it.

Answer (score 10):

Caveat: I'm not familiar with the Enthought Distribution, so this might not help.

As you're trying to install on Windows, if you don't want to have to mess around with C compilers, there are pre-built binary wheels for pygame here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Select a package appropriate to you python version[0] and Windows architecture [1]. Download to `C:\Users\User\Download\pip install E:\env\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` and install with `pip install E:\env\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

[Mercurial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mercurial) can be found on the same page, if you would like to install from source. This method would mean compiling pygame from source, for which you probably want to use [this compiler package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

[0] `python --version`

[1] `powershell "gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture"`

Comment: For me on Windows this was the easiest way to get pygame installed. Thanks!

Comment: Use 32-bit or 64-bit based on your Python install not your system architecture.

Comment: This worked for me too.  Follow the instructions, download the package and install from the download folder.  Example:   pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 7):

The command below worked for me on Mac OS X El Capitan:

`pip3 install pygame`

Answer (score 6):

Install on MAC:

```
brew install homebrew/python/pygame
```

Comment: I'm under OS X EI Capitan, this solution doesn't work : `/usr/local/include/pngconf.h:45:12: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found`

Answer (score 6):

The most current, the best way to install pygame is always available at:
https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

How to use pip depends on the operating system. So unless you have always updated and tested answers for 15 different operating systems then just send people to that page. All answers to this question are wrong for various different operating systems.

Currently, for windows, this is the way to install it in the cmd prompt. (If you already have pip installed, and people know what pip is... best just send people to the GettingStarted page).

`py -m pip install pygame --user`

Answer (score 5):

Just

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Had this issue on macOS Sierra, where apt-get doesn't work.

Managed to solve the issue through the following steps:

First I had to install the Mercurial via Brew:

```
brew install mercurial
```

Then, I had to install Pygame dependencies:

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi
```

Finally I used pip3 to install Pygame:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

This worked twice for me on windows 7 and windows 10

Answer (score 4):

I did use these instructions  [here](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)  from the official site.
But i had to change the python3 part of the command to just py.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `python -m pip install pygame`

Or: `py -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 3):

Try `pip install pygame` or `pip3 install pygame`.

These should work for you.

If this does not work for you put `-m` before `pip` and `python` before 
 `-m`.

If putting `-m` does not work try reinstalling python

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on windows, the command below should work fine

```
 pip install pygame
```

If you are working on Linux, the command below should work fine

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Answer (score 3):

Type this in command prompt

`pip install pygame`

or

`py -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 3):

**WINDOWS**

If you are on a windows 10 device then you should use this command but first make sure you have Python installed from https://python.org, if you do run this in command prompt

```
py --version
```

and then whatever version it says you have (which you downloaded) keep it in mind we will use it later for now just incase try to upgrade pip incase you are on a outdated version I will be using 3.9 for the version for the rest of this as an example

```
py -3.9 -m pip --upgrade pip
```

After that if you have it already satisfied or it upgraded run this command in command prompt

```
py -3.9 -m pip install pygame
```

And wait for it to download
And to make sure it worked run this

```
py -3.9 -m pygame --version
```

If it shows the version you downloaded it!

**MacOS**

For MacOS do the same but then run this command to install it

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

or if it wont work

```
py -3.9 -m pip install -U pygame --user      ( or just pip3 )
```

to see if it worked run this

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

or

```
py -3.9 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

I hope this helped

Answer (score 2):

I have never used Enthought distribution, but you could try to use Anaconda distribution which is also great too.

Anaconda Distribution (Any OS):

From the docs:

> Update conda to the current version.
>   Type the following:

```
conda update conda
```

> If a newer version of conda is available, type y to update:
>   Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Check to see if a package you have not installed named
>   “pygame” is available from the Anaconda repository (must be
>   connected to the Internet):

```
conda search pygame
```

> Conda displays a list of all packages with
>   that name on the Anaconda repository, so we know it is available.
>
> Install this package into the current environment:

```
conda install pygame
```

> Check to see if the newly installed
>   program is in this environment:

```
conda list
```

Install on Windows (both python 2.7 and 3.7):

```
pip install pygame
```

Install on raspberry pi:

```
sudo pip3 install pygame (python 3.7)
sudo pip install pygame (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you go to Command Prompt and type

```
py -m pip install pygame
```

that's what works for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way: `sudo install pygame` Rasberry pi has it ready-installed

Comment: Probably could be a comment

Answer (score 2):

Install python 3.8 from python.org
Then install pygame (2.0) like this
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10

Answer (score 2):

Make sure script path is registered in environment variables,
Make sure the python path is registered in environment variables,
also you dont have to enter entire url just write like this(windows only I dont use mac)

```
pip
pip install pygame
```

hope it work

Comment: This answer is no different than most of the other 28 answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29667684)

Answer (score 2):

command to install pygame is:

```
pip install pygame
```

run it in command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this for python3:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==1.9.6
```

and this for python2:

```
python -m pip install pygame==1.9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

To install `pygame` with `pip`, use the following commands in the `Command Prompt` on Windows.

```
py -m pip download pygame
```

then...

```
py -m pip install pygame
```

You only have to do the `download pygame` one if it doesn't work when you use the `install pygame` command by itself.

You type `py -m` to show that it is using the module `pip`, which can be accessed through the command prompt.

This is for Windows. For Mac OS, use `python -m pip install pygame`

Comment: This works for **Windows** as @NumberOneRobot asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to type in the entire url. Just simply go to command prompt (windows) or terminal (mac) and then type in:

[windows] `pip install pygame`
[mac] `python -m install pygame`

hopefully that works :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that there are already lot's of answers, but if you want to download a specific version of pygame, you can use pip:

```
pip install pygame==1.9.6
```

Pygame 1.9.6 is the latest version at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame tells you how to install it [here](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted), in my personal experience this is what I do on windows to install it, open up command prompt and type `python -m pip install pygame` if that fails, check if you have more than one version of python installed if so you need to specify what version for example `python3.5 -m pip install pygame` the reason we do this from command prompt is that in the Python shell it doesn't understand what pip install is just to break it down a little python -m calls a python module in this case we want pip the next two arguments are what we want pip to do and what module/addon we want the action to be applied too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I disagree that my answer is unclear I clearly include a link to pygame's official installation instructions and then continue on to explain my personal experience of installing the module including when I've had more than one version of python on my computer I then explain why we don't do it in python's shell and what the command actually does I also was reading the "how to write good answers" while making the comment or I'd of just said hey do this

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run command prompt in administrator mode. To run in administrator mode:

1. Type command prompt in Windows search bar.
2. Right click on the command prompt option and click 'Run as administrator'.
3. Windows will ask you if you want to allow the app to make changes to your device. Click 'Yes'.
4. Command prompt will open in administrator mode.

Then type the following:

```
pip3 install pygame
```