# Trouble installing pygame inside virtualenv

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to install pygame inside a virtualenvs on windows (I use powershell-virtualenwrapper).
But when I run pip install hg+http://www.bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame it fail with this log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pygame\Scripts\pip run on 05/22/15 14:39:29
Downloading/unpacking hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
  Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build
  Found command 'hg' at 'C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseHg\\hg.exe'
  Running command "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" clone --noupdate -q http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build
  Running command "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" update -q
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build\setup.py) egg_info for package from hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Path for SDL not found.
    Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
    Path for FONT not found.
    Path for IMAGE not found.
    Path for MIXER not found.
    Path for SMPEG not found.
    Path for PNG not found.
    Path for JPEG not found.
    Path for PORTMIDI not found.
    Path for FFMPEG not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    Error with the "Setup" file,
    perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build\setup.py", line 174, in <module>
        extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\extension.py", line 168, in read_setup_file
        line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 387, in expand_makefile_vars
        s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:




WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"

Using WINDOWS configuration...



Path for SDL not found.

Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"

Path for FONT not found.

Path for IMAGE not found.

Path for MIXER not found.

Path for SMPEG not found.

Path for PNG not found.

Path for JPEG not found.

Path for PORTMIDI not found.

Path for FFMPEG not found.

Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.

Path for COPYLIB_z not found.

Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.

Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.



If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck

the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.





Continuing With "setup.py"

Error with the "Setup" file,

perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build\setup.py", line 174, in <module>

    extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\extension.py", line 168, in read_setup_file

    line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 387, in expand_makefile_vars

    s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pyGame\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pyGame\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pyGame\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pyGame\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Users\Marci\.virtualenvs\pyGame\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\marci\appdata\local\temp\pip-fyauuh-build
```

Comment: There's answer to your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869101/unable-to-install-pygame-using-pip