# pip install livewires gets no matching distribution found for pygame

Tags: python, installation, pip, livewires

I am getting the following errors when run `pip install livewires`:

```
Collecting livewires
  Using cached LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz
Collecting pygame (from livewires)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from livewires) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame (from livewires)
```

I am in Mac with python 2.7.10, and this package can not be installed through my editor (Pycharm) neither.

Comment: Related/duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869101/unable-to-install-pygame-using-pip

Answer (score 0):

> Using cached LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz

Maybe there is a problem with the cached version. Try using the [`--no-cache-dir`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/?highlight=#cmdoption--no-cache-dir) flag to force a fresh download.

```
pip install --no-cache-dir livewires
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I re-tried with the "pip install --no-cache-dir livewires" , it is now saying “Downloading LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz" instead of "Using cached LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz" . While still get the error messages :   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from livewires) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame (from livewires)......It's weird